# Why are 'and' and 'or' not functions in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, boolean, racket

I am using `map` to test a list of values to see if they have a given property. Then, I want to see if they all have that property and return `true` [iff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) they all do.

So my first idea was to just give `and` the list as `(and (list #t #t #f))` but that seems to treat the entire `(#t #t #f)` as boolean true and returns it.

So, I figured I could use `foldl`. I know that `(foldl + 0 (list 1 2 3))` works I figured that `(foldl and #t (list #t #t #f))` should work as well... but it doesn't.

In [DrRacket](http://racket-lang.org/)(using `#lang racket`) I get the error "`and: bad syntax in: and`", which isn't too helpful, but on [Repl.it](http://repl.it/GHX) (which uses [BiWaScheme](http://www.biwascheme.org/)) I get the error "`Error: #<Syntax and> is not a function`".

So, I'm guessing that `and` is a macro? Supporting this it seems if I just evaluate `+` I get `#<procedure:+>`, but for `and` I get `and: bad syntax in: and` (stranglely, `xor` is a procedure but `or`, `nor`, and `nand` are not).

So, is it a macro or something (probably to facilitate short-circuiting)? And if so what is the boolean *function* that will perform the "and" operation?

Comment: how about NOT ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `and` is a macro. But you can turn it into function with

```
(lambda (x y) (and x y))
```

as in

```
(foldl (lambda (x y) (and x y)) #t your-list)
```

Comment: `and` is described [here](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.2.1).

Comment: @Doug Currie is there an already existing function I could reuse instead of wrapping `and` (I'm new to Scheme, but it does seem dirty). I assume the macro is using such a function, or would it be handled all with `if`s internally?

Comment: Some schemes have a function called `every` that does what you're looking for -- it's a combination of `reduce` and `and`. `every` is in SRFI-1. Your example would be `(every id your-list)` where `id` is `(lambda (x) x)`.

Comment: Ah, yes there is [every](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi-std/srfi-1.html#every) and there is also [any](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi-std/srfi-1.html#any) for doing `or`.

Comment: Racket calls those functions `andmap` and `ormap`. (You can also get them under the names `every` and `any` from `srfi/1`.)

Comment: Also, `id` is `identity` in Racket :)

Answer (score 8):

Other answers have already explained how to use `and` "as if" it were a function, but the reason `and` is a macro is to support the "short circuiting" behavior you're accustomed to from other languages. eg, `(and #f (display "blah"))` won't print anything, because `and` stops as soon as it sees a false value. If `and` were a function, both of its arguments would necessarily be evaluated before calling it, and then the `display` would happen regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have already explained why `and` is not a function directly, but the underlying reason in the design of the language is still to be revealed a little more.

There are core reasons:

1. Scheme provides functions as [procedures](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.1.4). [A call of procedure](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.1.3) requires [applicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Applicative_order) of operands (except the evaluation order among operands is unspecified), which is a case of [strict evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy), where all operands are required to be evaluated in a call.
2. The [`and` expression in Scheme](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.2.1) needs to support "short circuit" evaluation of operands ("any remaining expressions are not evaluated" after "the first expression that evaluates to a false value"), i.e. a case of [non-strict evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Non-strict_evaluation), where not all operands are necessarily evaluated in the call.

These requirements of using procedures and supporting short circuit evaluation are logically inconsistent, so you cannot have them coexisted in the language. Macros can support non-strict evaluations [by expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_macro_expansion), so here they are.

However, the limitation above is due to Scheme's design choice. The notion of functions and non-strict evaluation do not clash in nature. In a language providing "functions" (other than Scheme's procedures) supporting non-strict evaluation, similar constructs can be actually implemented. Notably, [the Kernel language](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/~jshutt/kernel.html), as a Scheme-like derivation, provides both applicative combiners (like Scheme's procedures) and operative combiners (replacement of macros but being first-class like procedures, e.g. allowing being passed to another combiner as an operand), which can be collectively considered "functions". The standard derivations (non-primitive combiners) in the language include *both* `$and?` (an operative as Scheme's `and` macro, with short circuit evaluation) and `and?` (an applicative which guarantees the operand always evaluated first, like an ordinary strict-evaluating function). Klisp, as an implementation, provides the derivation of `$and?` as the distinguishing example in [its homepage](http://klisp.org).